# How short path to convert my home partition(encrypted) ext4 to btrfs?

Tags: encryption, home-directory, ext4, btrfs

What steps should I take to convert my / home (ext4) partition to btrfs

It will be worth it, because in the past (2 years or more) I have used this file system, but I had some problems, especially regarding dockers. (problems occurred and I was unable to delete files or folders, having to format)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/198000/how-can-i-convert-an-ext4-partition-to-btrfs-or-other-file-systems-without-los

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert an ext4 partition to btrfs (or other file systems) without losing data?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198000/how-can-i-convert-an-ext4-partition-to-btrfs-or-other-file-systems-without-los)

Comment: @karel yes, thank you

Comment: @MrCandido If the link answered your question please confirm it by clicking the "Yes" option next to "Does this answer your question?" in the light blue banner above your question.